# Error 500 php require_once no localizado al reemplazar archivo en producción apache2

Tags: php, apache, apache2

Hace días actualice una función de un proyecto y reemplace el archivo viejo con el nuevo directamente con la terminal "sudo mv ..." reemplazando el archivo original en la ruta de producción.

Al hacer eso cualquier parte del sitio arrojaba error 500. El archivo error.log indicaba que el archivo que pide a través de require_once que recién reemplace es inaccesible.

Durante una hora intente revirtiendo los cambios reemplazando el archivo nuevo con una versión anterior pero el error.log seguía indicando lo mismo.

Probé comandos para cambiar los permisos para el usuario www-data y no servía.

Eventualmente el proyecto dejo de tirar error, y se ejecutó bien con el archivo nuevo repitiendo todos intentos.

Talvez omití algún detalle de la razón que lo provocó, incluso pude acertar en la solución, pero como ningún intento dio una solucion inmediatamente no me voy a adjudicar la solución, me gustaría que los experimentados me orienten e indiquen qué tomar en cuenta a la hora de actualizar parte de un proyecto en producción.

El proyecto está montado en un servidor físico que corre Ubuntu 20, con apache2. El proyecto está hecho en php con estructura MVC.

Se habían reemplazado partes del proyecto usando la terminal y ejecutando un move (sudo mv) pero solo en esta ocasión al reemplazar el archivo más importante todo el servidor arrojaba error 500.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que al reemplazar el archivo por el nuevo los permisos hayan cambiado.
Revisa la propiedad del archivo quizá el nuevo propietario es root u otro diferente:

ls -lia

Desde ahí mismo revisa que los permisos sean correctos 0644 para archivo y 0755 para carpetas.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, pero aplique los permisos a la carpeta /www/html/ raiz con modo recursivo para el usuario y grupo www-data, que es el usuario con el que trabaja apache2. Tal vez no use las instrucciones adecuadas porque recién aprendo de comandos y tuve un golpe de suerte, qué me recomiendas aplicar siempre después de cada actualización?